# Unable to get list of attached camera

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

When i execute this code it gives error in console like this

```
Uncaught NotSupportedError: The implementation did not support the requested type of object or operation. 
(anonymous function)
```

My code is :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

      <meta name="description" content="Get multiple video streams on one page. Adapted from code by Muaz Khan">

      <title>Video Camera List</title>

      <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js" ></script>

      <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        video {
          border:1px solid gray;
        }
      </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
   // alert('Hiii');
      if (!MediaStreamTrack) document.body.innerHTML = '<h1>Incompatible Browser Detected. Try <strong style="color:red;">Chrome Canary</strong> instead.</h1>';

      var videoSources = [];

      MediaStreamTrack.getSources(function(media_sources) 
    {
        console.log(media_sources);

        media_sources.forEach(function(media_source){
          if (media_source.kind === 'video') {
            videoSources.push(media_source);
          }
        });

        getMediaSource(videoSources);
      });

      var get_and_show_media = function(id) {
        var constraints = {};
        constraints.video = {
          optional: [{ sourceId: id}]
        };

        navigator.webkitGetUserMedia(constraints, function(stream) {
          console.log('webkitGetUserMedia');
          console.log(constraints);
          console.log(stream);

          var mediaElement = document.createElement('video');
          mediaElement.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
          document.body.appendChild(mediaElement);
          mediaElement.controls = true;
          mediaElement.play();

        }, function (e) {
          document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('hr'));
          var strong = document.createElement('strong');
          strong.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(e);
          document.body.appendChild(strong);
        });
      };

      var getMediaSource = function(media) {
        console.log(media);
        media.forEach(function(media_source) {
          if (!media_source) return;

          if (media_source.kind === 'video') {
            // add buttons for each media item
            var button = $('<input/>', {id: media_source.id, value:media_source.id, type:'submit'});
            $("body").append(button);
            // show video on click
            $(document).on("click", "#"+media_source.id, function(e){
              console.log(e);
              console.log(media_source.id);
              get_and_show_media(media_source.id);
            });
          }
        });
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try out this...

type it **chrome://flags/** on google chrome.

Enable WebRTC device enumeration and also enable getUserMedia.

[image]